# Need to update particular column in one csv using value of another csv but whole row get updated

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I m writing a python code using pandas where I have to update afew columns in one CSV-file using another CSV-file. I am getting the wrong output. It is update the whole row with that value.

```
lcsv.loc[['Track_id']][l1[k]] = l2[k]
lcsv.to_csv('modified.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: please provide samples according to the guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you want to achieve, what have you tried, and what exactly did not work?

Comment: I have two csv . now in which i have to compare few columns if they are same then i have to update the particular from one csv using the value of another csv. I am using list to store the compare value and then updating it. but it is not updating .

Answer (score -1):

for k in range(len(l4)) :
for p in range(len(l1)):

```
    if( (l4[k]==l1[p]) & (l5[k] == l3[p]) & (l6[k] > 2000) ):
         lcsv.loc[ l4[k] , 'Track_id'] = l2[p]
         lcsv.to_csv('modifient.csv' , index = False)
        
       this is my code.
```

Comment: You see the problem with the formatting, right?